# Is it normal to put CSS styling in the value of a "class" attribute as opposed to a "style" element?

Tags: html, css

I was looking at the support tab on The Odin Project website in Inspect, and I noticed this:

`<a class=" text-sm border-transparent text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-300 hover:border-gray-300 hover:text-gray-700 inline-flex items-center px-1 pt-1  border-b-2 font-medium " data-test-id="nav-support-us" data-turbo-method="get" href="/support_us">Support us</a>`

1. Is this a normal occurrence for web developers, to put CSS styling here in the value of a class attribute?
2. If yes, then do we really even need a separate CSS sheet or `style` element? I assume it would just be a matter of preference...
3. If no, then why might the web developer(s) have used this method as opposed to a `style` element or a CSS sheet?

I have only ever heard of a CSS sheet or `style` element being the place to describe the content of a web page, so this is completely strange to me and I have no idea how to explain it. I'm curious to know what the best option is to better aid my development journey.

Comment: This looks like they use a library (which is a `.css` file)  that defines all those classes, so yes it's normal to define styles in a class of a HTML element.

Comment: There is no styling in the list of class attributes.    `dark:` and `hover:` are class qualifiers that will only be used under certain conditions.  `font-medium` is the name of a CSS class that probably does `font-size: medium`.

Comment: Even something like `hover:text-gray-700` is just a class name, rather than an actual style. There's just a long list of class names there, which will all have their styles set within a style sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you're seeing is a common practice in modern web development, and it's known as inline styling using utility classes. This approach is often associated with frameworks like [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/).

Tailwind CSS is a utility-first CSS framework that provides a set of pre-defined utility classes that you can directly use in your HTML markup. Instead of creating a separate CSS file or using a style element, developers can apply styles directly in the HTML by adding classes to elements.

```html
<a class="text-sm border-transparent text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-300 hover:border-gray-300 hover:text-gray-700 inline-flex items-center px-1 pt-1 border-b-2 font-medium" data-test-id="nav-support-us" data-turbo-method="get" href="/support_us">Support us</a>
```

Each class in the class attribute corresponds to a specific styling rule, such as text size (text-sm), border color (border-transparent), text color (text-gray-500), and so on. This approach provides a more granular and modular way to apply styles.